Can I add the wiki to the original non-wiki repository, or achieve the wiki functionality otherwise?
I have created a wiki using the GitLab web application, but I never have to commit anything to the repository to add the wiki, it got added automatically.
When I do git pull in my IDE, nothing gets pulled. I understand that the wiki is actually a separate repository under the hood, as per the GitLab Wiki. It even says "If you don’t want to keep your documentation in your repository, but you want to keep it in the same project as your code" - well no, I DO want the documentation in the repository, but not as a long Readme, but as a wiki that can be browsed by topic.
Can I change it so it will be committed along with the code repository? Or how can I get a wiki-type structure on the web app and still have, say, a wiki/ folder with .md files for download in the repository?


Can I add the wiki to the original non-wiki repository, or achieve the wiki functionality otherwise?

Wiki is normal separate git repo. You can git add files and git commit from .gitlab-ci pipeline from your main project to that wiki repo.

how can I get a wiki-type structure on the web app

You can similarly deploy gitlab-pages.

The pages option adds even more overhead than the wiki, and I don't think it is an alternative. Is a nested repository common practice here? I.e. the wiki as a sub-repo of the main repo? I don't want to open another question for this.

Is a nested repository common practice here? No. Git submodules aby themselves re a common practice for dependency management. the wiki as a sub-repo of the main repo? No. Usually people manage wiki pages as a separate project than the main project. The main reason is release procedures and reviews, releasing something requires recompilation. Wiki is just documentation that can be edited easily. If you want to keep it in, then just use the first recommendation.
